# ffmpeg create thumbnail sprites with duplicate frames

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm using ffmpeg to create thumbnail sprites for a video player and the player requires a sprite to be 101 frames. For videos that have less then 101 frames in total, I'm trying to add some frames multiple times to the sprite, for example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -frames 1 -q:v 1 -vf "select=eq(n\,0)+eq(n\,0)+eq(n\,1)+eq(n\,1)+eq(n\,2)+eq(n\,2)...+eq(n\,30)+eq(n\,30),scale=178:134,tile=101x1" output.jpg
```

With this command ffmpeg is skipping the duplicate frames and adding black frames to the end of the sprite.
[Sprite example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvIeW.jpg)

Is it possible to let ffmpeg add duplicate frames?

Comment: Do you want to duplicate only some frames?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, I have a list of the frames I want